# How to add custom style to a HTML element in ejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I am creating a Bug tracking system as a project to learn Node.js. The problem I am encountering is that I want to change the table row(in the below screenshot) background color with respect to the value of the status(like for OPEN I want the color red, green for closed etc).

```html
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Project</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Date Created</th>
            <th>Bug</th>
            <!--  -->
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Date Solved</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>     
    <tbody>
        <% bugs.forEach(function(bugs){ %>
        <tr id ="color">
            <td><a style="text-decoration:none" href="/"><%= bugs.projectName%></a></td>
            <td><%= bugs.status %> 
                <% if (bugs.status === "OPEN") { %>
                <% document.getElementById("color").style.color = "green"; %>
                <% } %>                         
            </td>
            <td><%= bugs.dateCreated %></td>
            <td><a style="text-decoration:none; color : #000;" href="/bugs/<%= bugs._id %>"><%= bugs.title %></a></td>
            <td><a style="text-decoration:none; color : #000;" href="/bugs/<%= bugs._id %>"><%= (bugs.description).substr(0, 40) %></a></td>
            <td><%= bugs.dateSolved %></td>
        </tr>  
        <% }); %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The error produced :

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrifT.jpg)

Comment: You'll want to use `style.backgroundColor` instead of `style.color` if you're wanting to change the background color rather than the text color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<tr>` should not have an `id` since it likely repeats several times on your page. I believe a `class` would be more appropriate here. More info on the differences between ids and classes https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/.

I think something like this added to your `<tr>` might do the trick.

```
<tr style="<%= bugs.status === 'OPEN' ? 'color: green' : '' %>">
```

One thing to keep in mind; most people look down on in-line styles like my example. An better option would be to make a style class that had all the styling you want for your "open" rows and applying that class using a similar ternary like I showed above.

```
// somewhere in your stylesheet
.open-bug { color: green; }
<tr class="<%= bugs.status === 'OPEN' ? 'open-bug' : '' %>">
```

Comment: I think you should use single quotes rather than double quotes for 'OPEN'.

Comment: @ChristopherBradshaw thanks for catching that. I've updated my answer. For reference: it needs to be single quotes because it's inside a set of double quotes already.

Comment: Glad to be of help. If you wouldn't mind selecting my answer as the one that worked for you it can help future programmers with your same challenge. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

EJS is rendered on the server, not the browser, so EJS has no idea what `document` is since that's something that's only defined in the browser.

You can solve your issue by using inline styles similar to how Dan did in his answer above.